# Device/Browser Registration

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I need to develop an application that registers the device/browser that the user is using.  Such as banks or better yet FB does.  So for example when a person logs in the application checks to see if they have logged in using that device/browser before.  If not then have them go through a verification process.

The application will be built in .Net 4, Asp.Net MVC, js, jQuery, etc..

I hoping to get some advice on what others have used to accomplish this task.

***EDIT***

Thanks for the comments.

Ok, so basically, if am understanding correctly, both suggestions would mean storing a uniqueid  in a cookie/localStorage on a Laptop/Device and also in my DB so i can recognize it in the future.

I was hoping, to be able to get a unique ID from the machine/device that is static and specific to machine/device so that I can use to track it.  My concept would mean that a user would have several devices/machines that i have logged in from.

I will also be capturing the IP but i don't want to use that Key to identifying a user.

Comment: Use localStorage - it's the newer version of cookies for HTML5.
[Tutorial here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: You may check out the "User-Agent-String" and/or setting cookies. However both can be manipulated/deleted (e.g. due to expiration) so you cannot be 100% sure. Depending on your use-case this however is not necessiarly a problem i think.

Comment: @NischaalCooray: Umm, no, localStorage is *not* "the newer version of cookies for HTML5". It can store data client-side, like a cookie, but that's where the similarity ends. The main difference, though, is that cookie data is sent to the server, whereas localStorage data is client-side only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chances of getting a precisely unique identifier from a browser is slim to none. There are many privacy risks associated with browsers providing a unique identifier string. However, you can always generate a random GUID for a session a user establishes, and store it either as localStorage or as a cookie.

Comment: Yes thank you that is what the comments also suggested.  I have never tried this so I wasnt sure if there was a possible way.

Comment: @ChampChris where did you get with this ? . My client has a similar requirement in that they want to track the number of devices on which each subscriber uses their service .The difficulty is that the service runs in a  browser . 
It seems all the possibly relevant html5 apis are browser bound with the one exception FileSystem api having been deprecated and only implemented on Chrome 

I'm down to 2 possible approaches 
- ActiveX/Applet/Flash (yuk!)
- Client Side Certificates : certs need to stored in common OS key store. test device unicity by attempting handshake that depends on cert

Comment: @diarmuid i dont exactly remember now.  I didnt use localStorage i know that.  If i remember correctly without looking at the code, what i did was store all the browser information (in the Request.browser object) and FK'ed it the user and the loginAttempt which also had the IP address so this way i knew every browser the user logged into from and every IP, so if the browser wasnt recognized, i would prompt them to verify with security key and register the browser with a name.  Hope that helps.